# C# Console Applications runs successfully only for second time for the day

Tags: c#

I am creating a console application and keep the SQL operations in a separate class file. When I execute the application it raises an exception:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

However, in SQL class file's constructor I wrote the code for `SqlConnection.Open()`.

**Code for Main application:**

```
using SQL;
class MyClass
{
    SQL.executeSQL runSQL=new SQL.executeSQL();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CheckCounts();
    }

    public void CheckCounts()
    {
        string sql="select count(*) from table_name";
        runSQL.executeQuery(sql);
    }
}
```

**Code for SQL class file:**

```
public class executeSQL
{
    SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["dbConnection"].ToString());
  public  executeSQL()
    {
        if(con.State!=ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
    }

    public void executeQuery(string sql)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(sql,con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

When I execute the application for the first time for that day it raises the exceptions as follows

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

But for next time it runs properly without any exception for the whole day.
Again if I run the application for the next day it raises the same exception and consecutive successful execution.

- *What should I do to run the application successfully for the first time of the day?*

I created a *batch file* for the application and I scheduled the task using the *Task Scheduler* with the batch file. If I run the application manually I do not get the error. Using the *Task Scheduler*, I am getting the error.

Comment: And calling `ExecuteNonQuery` from a method called `executeQuery` should ring some alarm bells.

Comment: function CheckCounts should be static, as should runSQL

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for a few reasons.

Chances are, you're connecting to a remote SQL server.
If this is the case, then there are a variety of reasons why the connection may be closed on you by the time you make your call.

Things like network dropouts etc can cause the connection between your app and SQL to break and require reconnection.
It can also be caused by the agreed timeout between your app and SQL being exceed, however I doubt this is the case given your code sample.

I have personally experienced issues where I have made what appears to be a valid connection to the server, and then on the very next line attempt to make a SQL query, only to receive the same error as yourself.

In those instances, I've added a check before making my SQL query around the `SQLConnection.State` property, which can return any of the following:

> **Broken**
>   The connection to the data source is broken. This can occur only after
>   the connection has been opened. A connection in this state may be
>   closed and then re-opened. (This value is reserved for future versions
>   of the product.)
>   **Closed** 
>   The connection is closed.
>   **Connecting**
>   The connection object is connecting to the data source.
>   **Executing**
>   The connection object is executing a command. (This value is reserved
>   for future versions of the product.)
>   **Fetching**
>   The connection object is retrieving data. (This value is reserved for
>   future versions of the product.)
>   **Open**
>   The connection is open.

If the `SqlConnection.State` is `Open`, then I run my SQL query as intended.
If it's `Closed`, I attempt to re-open it then re-call my SQL query.
If it's `Connecting`, I pause for a specific amount of time, then retest.

Depending on how you want your app to perform, I would look at either moving the creation of the `SQLConnection` into the method that makes the SQL call, as follows:

```
public class executeSQL
{           
     private void CheckSQLConnection(SqlConnection con)
     {
       ...
     }     
     public void executeQuery(string sql)
     {
         using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ToString()))
         {
             con.Open();
             using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
             {
                 CheckSQLConnection();
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
             con.Close();
         }
     }
 }
```

As in my example, it's also worth implementing `using` statements around your SQLConnection and SQLCommand objects to ensure they're properly disposed of and don't hang around, potentially holding onto SQL connections you might need.

Hope this helps!